# Can we post two answers(same user) in same question?

Tags: support, bug, answers

I am talking about this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280171/how-to-show-values-from-array-to-p-tag-by-swipping

[image]
The user seemed to be able to post two answers without deleting one. Is this correct or some mismatch ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes it's the best way, for example you've found a better solution. You should not edit your old answer, if it would be a radical change, and the post already has upvotes and/or many comments (it would be misleading for users wanting to judge your new answer on the basis of the votes to the old solution).

Then the best it is to post your new solution as new answer and let the community to judge it independently.

Answer (score 4):

The system does allow you to post two answers on the same question.

[image: add another answer]